# Findcontrol in listview itemtemplate

Tags: asp.net, linq, listview, itemtemplate

I have the next code in itemtemplate:

```
 <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>

  <asp:HiddenField Value='<%# checkCatName(Eval("CatName")) %>' runat="server" />
           ........
   <asp:Label runat="server" id="lblBla" Visible="false"> ... </asp:Label>

      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Code Behind (C#):

```
public void checkCatName(object CatName)
{
    Label bla = (Label)ListView1.FindControl("lblBla");


    if (CatName.ToString() == "test1")
        bla.Visible = true;


    return CatName.ToString();

}
```

I get null - like the page dont find the "bla" label.

Where i'm wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

to get item which is in the listview or a repeater, you will need to go through items in this view and then find control (hidden field).

Page will not be able to find that control directly.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If the listview has an itemdatabound event you can use it to find the control and do what ever you need with it. The following code is assuming you have a hidden field in your listview item template with the id="myhiddenfield"

```
//this goes inside your listview's itemdatabound event
HiddenField myhiddenfield = new HiddenField();
myhiddenfield = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("myhiddenfield");

//get or set hidden field value here.
int myID = Convert.ToInt32(myhiddenfield.Value);
```

Comment: here's another sample. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemdatabound.aspx